# triger que se solo actulice un campo cuando se ingresa una transaccion

Tags: sql, postgresql

tengo la tabla transacción que tiene

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.transacciones
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 10 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 ),
    nombre character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    producto character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    total double precision NOT NULL,
    tipo character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    iva double precision NOT NULL,
    pago character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    descuento double precision NOT NULL,
    fecha date NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT transacciones_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
END;
```

y la tabla activo con

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.activos
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    nombre character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    saldo double precision NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT activos_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

la tabla activos tiene datos en nombre de caja,inventario,iva, mobiliario,cuentas por cobrar , pero 0 en saldo

estaba intentando algo como esto

```
create function cajacompra() returns trigger as
$$
begin
insert into transacciones values (new.id,new.nombre,new.producto,new.total,new.tipo,new.iva,new.pago,new.descuento,new.fecha);
set @result = (select sum(total)from transacciones where transacciones.tipo=tipo.tipotransaccion)+ Select sum(caja) from activos);
 update activos set caja= @result
 return result

end;$$
Language plpgsql;
```

lo q tendria que hacer el trigger es que cuando se inserte una transacción el campo pago de la transacción se sume al campo caja de la tabla activo por ejemplo se hace una transaccion con pago de $1000 se sume a caja de la tabla activo que esta en 0, seria caja=caja+1000 mas o menos

pero me he perdido viendo tantos tutoriales

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Qué tipo de dato serán esos campos de esas tablas? Tendrás algunos datos de prueba para compartir? Podrías mostrar el resultado deseado de la ejecución del trigger a partir de los datos de prueba? Has intentado algo? Qué error te da? Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).